# Feedly is unable to read the feeds produced by our phpBB site

Tags: feeds, phpbb

On our site, the CEN64 forums, [feeds were recently requested to be enabled](http://forums.cen64.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=166). However, the feeds, while working for some feed readers, are showing up as empty in Feedly. While I personally think it's a Feedly bug, I'd like to know if there's a way to get it working from the phpBB side.

Just tested, and both Feedly and InoReader have the same problem, here is the feed: [CEN64 News](http://forums.cen64.com/feed.php?mode=news)

W3's tool confirms that it's generating a valid Atom 1.0 feed as well, and Feedreader.com is correctly displaying the content.

Does anyone know if there is something wrong with the Atom format that phpBB automatically creates that'd make these sites not properly read the feed when other programs, such as Slick RSS Reader read it no problem? If so, what are some options to avoid this bug?

More information can be found in the thread linked above.